# Programmatically opening a file just created

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a google worksheet with just scripts. I hope I understood this is the place to ask for this question.

On my Worksheet, I created a button for the user to close the WS and give a name to the next one.

Now that the WS is created, I need to get the ID to open that new file to "paste" some variables.

Two things I can't figure out how to do:

First, create the file on specific folder on my drive. 
Second, how do I read the ID of the file I just created to openById and then transfer the information?

a nice thing would be also to open the url so it would pop up on another tab.

Comment: This is the place to ask a specific question. As in yours like in most cases: What have you tried? Which code do you have and where does it not work? This place is wrong if you want to get new code from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [SpreadsheetApp.create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#create) to create the new Spreadsheet, then it returns an object of type Spreadsheet, on which you can call [Spreadsheet.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getId). That will give you the ID you need.

To move that spreadsheet to a particular folder, use [DocsList.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#getFileById) to get a File object and then [File.addToFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addToFolder).

Comment: ok, that's a good start. 
Now, how do I created the ws, I want to make couple of sheets programatically protected.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Jan clearly answered your first question about creating a file and getting the ID. As for your second question, know that it is impossible to get that file to pop up in another tab. Just imagine how much damage a coder could do popping up unlimited tabs.

The closest you can do is spreadsheet.getURL(), and then make a dialogbox with the URL contained inside. That way the user could click the URL and bring up the new spreadsheet.